# change project background color on android studio

Tags: android-studio, background, themes

I want to change the background color of project explorer.
As shown in following screenshot.[background color on my android-studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRPtP.jpg)

I want the color in the left to be the same in the right.It is eye-fit,whose value is #C7EDCC.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the `color-ide` plugin from [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7055?pr=clion).
2. Go to Preferences -> Plugins, choose "Install plugin from disk..." and select the downloaded .jar-file.
3. Restart Android Studio. You should be good to go since you already have the editor background color right.

More themes can be found at [sdvoynikov/color-themes](https://github.com/sdvoynikov/color-themes).

Comment: This doesn't change the top navigation bar color, though.  How to change the entire IDE color??